# How to use a Wifi Dongle on Raspbian to transform the Pi into an access point?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wireless

**Question**

How would I use a [Trendnet TEW-648UBM wifi usb dongle](http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=195_TEW-648UBM) in master mode to transform the Pi into an access point? (I am using Raspbian)

**Background**

The dongle seems to work out of the box; it loads the `driver 8192cu`, and can scan and connect to networks.

However, when i try to use it in master mode i get:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted.
```

The same error occurs when I use other `iwconfig` commands, such as `txpower`.

I also tried to use an open source driver provided by Realtek, [RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105](https://github.com/ninjablocks/rtl8192cu/tree/master/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v3.4.4_4749.20121105), but honestly I have no idea how to use it, and am afraid that if I install the driver, it will break the distribution

Thanks!

**Update**

Following the advices received here, i found out that in the last wheezy the kernel module is ok, as well as wpa-supplicant (unless you want WPS support).
The only things that have to be replaced are hostapd and the wireless-tools.

So simply uninstall wireless-tools and hostapd, then download the realtek package, and make/make install both wireless-tools and hostap

after, it will work as described in the tutorial linked by BigCowPi.

Just a note: using iwconfig directly now works for setting the card in master mode, but it still fails when using it to set the txpower. This might be a limitation of the driver, i don't know. I would appreciate if somebody could comment on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I has the same problem with my Edimax Nano USB wifi adapter. [I have a guide on my blog](http://bigcowpi.blogspot.com/2013/03/raspberry-pi-as-3g-huawei-e303-wireless.html) to setting that up as a wireless AP with a workaround for RTL 8188 chipsets.

If you don't want to visit my blog, [here is a link](http://www.jenssegers.be/blog/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi) to the guide I used originally.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this will solve the problems. Mind if i ask you also whether for you iwconfig works to set the txpower to 0, or lower in general? thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried this - when I get chance, I'll try it and let you know.